# Match on two items with regular expressions

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I am trying to do a `filter` on my Pandas data frame that contains columns with names such as `DE-NL`, `DE-FR`, `FR-NL`, `AT-DE` etc.

I need to filter my data frame so I only get the columns that contains two of a certain strings.

So basically, if I just do this:

```
df = df.filter(regex="DE|NL|FR")
```

Then it finds all columns where either of the three are in. So I might also get something like `AT-DE`. In this case I would actually only need the following columns:

```
DE-NL, NL-DE, NL-FR, FR-NL, DE-FR, FR-DE
```

So two of the filter strings needs to be present before it's a match.

Comment: What about `NL-NL`. Is this of any concern/allowed or not possible?

Comment: It can be allowed. But it doesn't exist, so I don't think it will cause any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.filter(regex="^(?:DE|NL|FR)-(?:DE|NL|FR)$")
```

To make it programmatically from a list of country codes:

```
l = ['DE', 'NL', 'FR']
s = '|'.join(l)

df = df.filter(regex=f"^(?:{s})-(?:{s})$")
```

If you want to avoid matching repeated values (e.g., 'NL-NL'):

```
l = ['DE', 'NL', 'FR']
s = '|'.join(l)

df = df.filter(regex=fr"^({s})-(?!\1)(?:{s})$")
```